# Android TextEdit blue line dissapeared

Tags: android, input, textview, textfield, underline

quick question.
In All my android layouts for some reason the blue line which underlines the TextEdit fields has dissapeared.
http://developer.android.com/images/ui/edittext-noextract.png
The one which is under the 'TO'
i've tryed playing around with the properties but i can't get it back.
The text field is the same color as the background so i really need the line to appear for aesthetical purposes.
Which property do i have to set? Thanks!

Comment: Did you change style properities?

Comment: Could be, i'm new to android so i'm still making the mistake of changing things without knowing exactly what i changed. which property defines it in the style?

Comment: styles.xml is located in res/values/ directory, you could check that.